# I can't download anything in Ubuntu system

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

**Whenever I execute the command `sudo apt upgrade`, it's saying**:

```
following packages have unmet dependencies:

libpam-modules : PreDepends: libpam-modules-bin (= 1.3.1-5ubuntu4) but 1.3.1-5ubuntu4.1 is installed
Recommends: update-motd but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

**Then I executed the command `sudo apt --fix-broken install`
it gives the following error**:

```
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Could not exec dpkg!
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)
```

Comment: We don't know your OS & release details, and you've only provided a few of the messages that need to be read to fix your issue.  Summary detail (such as *returned an error code*) is telling you to look at prior messages.

Comment: I would suggest reading the output of `sudo apt update` and look for missing lines, or issues with it, as `rmadison libpam-modules-bin` will shows clues as to the message you did provide.

Comment: i am using  Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: when i executing the command sudo apt update , its saying                                            
"E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423) focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default."

Comment: If you add additional information, please edit & add it there, it allows greater formatting options and is thus easier to understand. The 'cdrom' refers to your installation media & that's a non-issue (you can easily disable that repository (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) but the lines I was meaning will occur after that, or I suspected a '-updates' line will be missing which is required.  An `apt-cache policy libpam-modules-bin` will also reveal details, but `sudo apt update` shows messages so operators can detect issues there thus not need to run `apt-cache policy`..

Answer (score 0):

`Aptitude` is amazing !!! It has solved many such issues.

Try using it: `sudo aptitude install <package-name>`.
or
You may even try `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade`.

**FYI** - This requires aptitude to be installed. If you don't have it run `sudo apt-get install aptitude`.

Good luck